# JVM heap space allocation is confusing

Tags: java, jvm

I have a `java` application running with a max heap size of 8 GB .

On a 32 GB memory, the slice of Old gen was 7.4 GB(approx) . In a 128 GB memory, the same application gets a slice of Old Gen of 6.2 GB(approx).

I would like to know how this is done by the `JVM` internally? Is there a math that it uses. Actually , am in the phase of `GC` tuning and would be helpful if I get to know how this number is arrived by default. I use `JDK` 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

It does not have to do with the total RAM in the system. The GC ratios affect how much memory can exist in various regions.

> -XX:NewRatio=n    Ratio of old/new generation sizes. The default value is 2.
>
> -XX:SurvivorRatio=n   Ratio of eden/survivor space size. The default value is 8.
>
> -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70   Maximum percentage of heap free after GC to avoid shrinking.

Use the first 2 ratios to tweak the ratio of the heap internally within the VM itself. Use the free heap ratios to tweak the amount of memory that the heap can grow / shrink by.

Recommended reading - Oracle provided [GC tuning guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#generation_sizing.total_heap).

Comment: But as a matter of fact, i have not set any of the JVM tunning metrics. My question is, by default, memory is getting allocated. How it is different for two different machines for the same application with same max heap setting?

Comment: It is quite possible that different loads cause different memory profiles across 2 machines. Unless you get a load test to give you a consistent load between 2 machines with the same JVM and tuning parameters, your comparison does not hold.

Comment: Thanks Bala. I was looking for that . The load is actually zero as both are dedicated machines. So, memory profiles do determine the parts of JVM heap. Shall i take like that?

Comment: If the load is zero, why would survivor space have many objects at all ? Tune the ratios / Get a load test that executes consistently / Compare the memory used in various regions based on the test. That is the way to go about it. And yes the ratios determine what parts of the heap take more memory.

Comment: The results what i posted are all pre-allocated numbers. The number i have mentioned is the amount of Old Gen space allocated out of 8 GB heap. Guess , you have mistook it as space used

Comment: If you're seeing different results in the internal split of allocated memory, the environment / configuration settings between the machines are not the same. I'd suggest tuning those parameters based on the guide.